# scrollViewWillBeginDragging in UITableView does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

```
UIScrollView|
UITableView
```

I have 5 `UITableView` in `UIScrollView`.

My program has a Navigation Controller inside TabbarController.
When I run the program, everything is OK. It can drag up and down to refresh data in tableview. It can drag left and right to change tableview.

But when I push the button on the Navigation Bar, it will push a view.
Then I push the back button on the navigation bar on this view.
The `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` in `UITableView` not worked. I can just receive the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` in `UIScrollView`.
More worse, it can drag all directions.

Why?

Comment: hi ,don't use five table.. you can mange through one table with five different cell ..and don't need scrollview bcs  no you have only one tableview....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already fix this bug , set self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;